# How do I update the status of an asset in VersionOne using the REST API

Tags: python, api, rest, versionone

How can I update the status of an asset in V1 using the Rest API?

I would assume I could do something like this using the Python SDK:

```
from v1pysdk import V1Meta

v1 = V1Meta()

for s in (v1.PrimaryWorkitem
          .filter("Number='D-01240'")):
  s.StoryStatus = v1.StoryStatus(134)

v1.commit()
```

This is at least how I understand the Python SDK examples here:
https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.Python

However this does not change anything, even though I have the rights to change the status.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
s.Status = v1.StoryStatus(134)
```

According to `~/meta.v1?xsl=api.xsl#PrimaryWorkitem` The attribute on `PrimaryWorkitem` of type `StoryStatus` is named `Status`, so I think it's just a mistaken attribute name.

What's probably happening is that you're setting a new attribute on that python object, but since `StoryStatus` is not one of the setters that the SDK created from the instance schema metadata, it doesn't attempt to add it to the uncommitted data collection, and thus the commit is a no-op and yields neither error nor any action.

It might be possible to fence off arbitrary attribute access on those objects so that misspelled names raise errors. I'll investigate adding that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
s.set(Status = v1.StoryStatus(134))
```